# Rewriting Kubernetes services in an Nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, url-rewriting, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have multiple APIs all listening on '/api' and a web front end listening on '/'.

Is there a way which I can write my ingress definition to rewrite the paths to something like the following?

```
/api/      -> /api/ on service1
/api2/api/ -> /api/ on service2
/api3/api/ -> /api/ on service3
/          -> /     on service4
```

I know I can change the APIs to listen to something else but don't want to do that. I know I can also just rewrite all to /api/ and let service3 act as the default but there may be other services which need routing elsewhere in the future.

I've heard that you could use multiple ingresses but I'm not sure how that would affect performance and if it's best practice to do so.

Also, is there any way to debug which route goes to which service?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from @Rahman - see other answer. I've managed to get this to work with a single ingress.

I've had to post this as an additional answer because of the character limit.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-name
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(api/.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api2/(api.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api3/(api.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service3
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service4
          servicePort: 80
```

Just for context for anyone else stumbling upon this in the future, service 1 is a main API, service 2 and 3 are other APIs under another subdomain and service 4 is a web frontend.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Nginx, you should be able to configure your Ingress for path matching like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: (/api/.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
          servicePort: 80
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress-2
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api2/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api3/.*
        backend:
          serviceName: service3
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /.*
        backend:
          serviceName: service4
          servicePort: 80
```

[More info](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I got the rewrite paths slightly wrong - I've updated the question :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've followed what you've provided but the APIs such as API2 don't seem to be working. Is there a way to debug what the path is getting rewritten to? I need API2 to listen on /api2/api/xyz but pass it to the service like /api/xyz
Also, are there any disadvantages of using multiple ingresses? It just seems a bit messy to me.

Comment: I should probably add the other routes (/api/ and /) work as expected. I just need to strip the "api2/" part out before forwarding the requests on to the service

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it working and have made an edit to your post (I hope that's okay). Do you know how I can get this to only be one ingress controller though?

Comment: Awesome @JamesB. I can see your edit. tho can you please check with `rewrite-target` only for both ingresses? I mean remove `use-regex` from second one and verify if it still works. Because I think one of them is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Rahman - I added another answer with the code in for a single ingress to achieve this so others stumbling upon this in the future can see.